# find files and folders by a user and then delete them by one ssh command?

Tags: file, ssh, directory

Tried using:

```
find /home/ -user student -exec rm -fr {}
```

or

```
find /home/ -group student -exec rm -fr {} \
```

but had error message: `find: missing argument to '-exec'`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

The easiest way (even mentioned in manual page for `[find(1)][1]`) is:

```
find /tmp -name core -type f -print | xargs /bin/rm -f
```

adapted to your case:

```
find /home/ -user student -print | xargs /bin/rm -rf
```

---

But certainly there are several variants how to accomplish this task. You can simply start from different example with `-exec`:

```
find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;
```

adapted to your use case:

```
find /home/ -group student -exec rm -rf '{}' \;
```